# Javascript / Lodash deep comparison object from an array of object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, lodash

Suppose i have an array of objects like this

```
let arr = [
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    ghijkl: {name: 'Simon', uid: '456'}
  },
  {
    mnopqr: {name: 'Alex', uid: '789'},
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}
  },
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    stuvwx: {name: 'Julianna', uid: '111'},
    yzxwuv: {name: 'Elon', uid: '007'}
  }
];
```

In position of `arr[0]`, `arr[1]` and `arr[2]`, i define a object and inside that object, i define couple of objects.

Here this `abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}` is common among the three(arr[0], arr[1], arr[2]). So i need to write a function that returns the common one.
In this case `abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}`

**UPDATE:**
If there is nothing in common, return false. And two or more in common, return all of them.

Comment: What will be returned if you have two in common?

Comment: Please add the code you've tried so far

Comment: @huanfeng if two or more in common, return all of them.

Comment: So, you want to make an intersection of object properties?

Comment: @VLAZ exactly, is there any way of using math union or intersection ?

Comment: @Robin I have updated my answer to show how to do it without ```lodash```, it's just for illustration in case someone doesn't want to use ```lodash```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can easily do that by using [`intersectionWith`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#intersectionWith) - it accepts a custom comparator for your elements. The easiest way is to convert the object into an array of entries using [`toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#toPairs) and then compare those with [`isEqual`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#isEqual). The intersection would then be an array containing pairs of attribute and value, so you can then convert it back to an object using [`fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#fromPairs)

```js
let arr = [
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    ghijkl: {name: 'Simon', uid: '456'}
  },
  {
    mnopqr: {name: 'Alex', uid: '789'},
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}
  },
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    stuvwx: {name: 'Julianna', uid: '111'},
    yzxwuv: {name: 'Elon', uid: '007'}
  }
];

const inputPairs = arr.map(_.toPairs);

const resultPairs = _.intersectionWith(...inputPairs, _.isEqual);

const resultObject = _.fromPairs(resultPairs);

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [chaining](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#lodash) this can be written as:

```js
let arr = [ { abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}, ghijkl: {name: 'Simon', uid: '456'} }, { mnopqr: {name: 'Alex', uid: '789'}, abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'} }, { abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}, stuvwx: {name: 'Julianna', uid: '111'}, yzxwuv: {name: 'Elon', uid: '007'} } ];

const resultObject = _(arr)
  .map(_.toPairs)
  .thru(pairs => _.intersectionWith(...pairs, _.isEqual))
  .fromPairs()
  .value();

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Using [`thru`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#thru) here because the chain contains an array with other array in it and each needs to be passed as a separate argument to `intersectionWith`. It's the easiest way to do that.

Alternatively, if you prefer a more [FP approach](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/wiki/FP-Guide) then it can look like this:

```js
const {spread, intersectionWith, isEqual, flow, map, toPairs, fromPairs} = _;

let arr = [ { abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}, ghijkl: {name: 'Simon', uid: '456'} }, { mnopqr: {name: 'Alex', uid: '789'}, abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'} }, { abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}, stuvwx: {name: 'Julianna', uid: '111'}, yzxwuv: {name: 'Elon', uid: '007'} } ];

const process = flow(
  map(toPairs), 
  spread(intersectionWith(isEqual)), 
  fromPairs
);

const resultObject = process(arr);

console.log(resultObject);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

Here's a quick solution I was able to whip up, and I am doing this without `lodash` intentionally just to illustrate how to do it natively

```js
    const arr = [
  {
    abcdef: { name: 'Robin', uid: '123' },
    ghijkl: { name: 'Simon', uid: '456' },
  },
  {
    mnopqr: { name: 'Alex', uid: '789' },
    abcdef: { name: 'Robin', uid: '123' },
  },
  {
    abcdef: { name: 'Robin', uid: '123' },
    stuvwx: { name: 'Julianna', uid: '111' },
    yzxwuv: { name: 'Elon', uid: '007' },
  },
];

function isEqual(a, b) {
  const aProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(a);
  const bProps = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(b);

  if (aProps.length !== bProps.length) {
    return false;
  }

  for (const prop of aProps) {
    if (a[prop] !== b[prop]) {
      return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}

function findIntersection() {
  const results = [];
  const objCount = {};

  arr.forEach(element => {
    Object.entries(element).forEach(entry => {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      if (!objCount[key]) {
        objCount[key] = {};
        objCount[key].value = value;
        objCount[key].count = 1;
      } else if (isEqual(value, objCount[key].value)) {
        objCount[key].count += 1;
      }
    });
  });

  Object.keys(objCount).forEach(key => {
    if (objCount[key].count === arr.length) {
      results.push({ [key]: objCount[key].value });
    }
  });

  if (results.length > 0) {
    return results;
  }
  return false;
}

const results = findIntersection(arr);
console.log('Results', results);
```

**Explanation**

The logic is as follows,

- Iterate over each array element and in turn over all the objects and keep a count of how many times they occur. Only increase the count if the key and value are both identical
- After getting the count for all the objects, iterate over each object's count value and check if it's equal to the number of elements in the array
  thus showing the object is common for all elements in the array
- For each object that satisfies the above condition push it to results array and return it

Hope this helps. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Just for your reference:

```
let arr = [
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    ghijkl: {name: 'Simon', uid: '456'}
  },
  {
    mnopqr: {name: 'Alex', uid: '789'},
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'}
  },
  {
    abcdef: {name: 'Robin', uid: '123'},
    stuvwx: {name: 'Julianna', uid: '111'},
    yzxwuv: {name: 'Elon', uid: '007'}
  }
];
let counterMap = {}, 
names=[], //names collect the keys only which exists in all item, here the value should be ['abcdef']
commons=[];
for (let itm of arr) {
  for (let key of Object.keys(itm)) {
    if (!counterMap[key]) {
      counterMap[key] = 1;
    } else {
      counterMap[key] = counterMap[key] + 1;
    }
  }
}
_.forOwn(counterMap, (val, key) => {
  if (val === arr.length) {
    names.push(key);
  }
})
names.forEach(name => {
  if (_.every(arr, itm => {
    return _.isEqual(itm[name], arr[0][name]);
  })){
    let result = {};
    result[name] = arr[0][name];
    commons.push(result)
  }
})
console.log(commons);
```

Comment: The only relevant use of Lodash here is `_.isEqual` and *somewhat* `_.forOwn`. However, the latter is trivially swappable with `for..of` and `Object.entries` or even just `Object.entries(x).forEach()` with pretty much no issue. And `_.every` can be replaced with `Array#every` with no loss in functionality.